# Hoursworked/day computation via Bio Logs

Tags: mysql

This is my *checkinout* table:

```
USERID  CHECKTIME            CHECKTYPE
------  -------------------  ---------
404     2016-02-12 07:24:03  I
404     2016-02-12 17:01:34  O
404     2016-02-15 07:24:21  I
404     2016-02-15 17:00:36  I
404     2016-02-16 07:09:01  I
404     2016-02-16 17:01:33  O
```

I used the script below to compute hoursworked/day, but the output gives my column *Hoursworked* huge value:

```
SELECT userid,Name
    DATE(CHECKTIME) AS date,
    SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CHECKTIME)*(1-2*checktype))/3600 AS hours_worked
    FROM CHECKINOUT
    GROUP BY date(CHECKTIME), userid;
```

Output:

```
Hoursworked  Userid  Date(Checktime)
-----------  ------  ---------------
NULL         404     2016-02-12
NULL         404     2016-02-12
NULL         404     2016-02-15
NULL         404     2016-02-15
NULL         404     2016-02-16
NULL         404     2016-02-16
```

How to resolve this issue?

My data source is inconsistent: our employee has the habit of multiple login\logout. Can you help where to eliminate the employee with incomplete I\O and for those having multiple login\out to get the first and last login\out logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long journey, this were i came up. Hope it helps to other, thank you all for giving me idea.

```
select Userid, Name, Campaign, Checktime, Hoursworked,

CASE WHEN timediff(Hoursworked,'09:00:00') > 0 THEN timediff(Hoursworked, '09:00:00') ELSE 0 END As Overtime

from
(
select 
a.userid,a.name,a.campaign,
date(a.CHECKTIME),
timediff(max(b.CHECKTIME), min(a.CHECKTIME)) as Hoursworked
from CHECKINOUT a
join CHECKINOUT b
on date(a.CHECKTIME) = date(b.CHECKTIME) and a.userid = b.userid
where
a.CHECKTYPE = 'I'
AND b.CHECKTYPE = 'O'
group by date(a.CHECKTIME), userid)
As T
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea I wrote in the comment http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/785bc/5 :

```
select 
    a.userid,
    date(a.CHECKTIME),
    timediff(max(b.CHECKTIME), min(a.CHECKTIME)) as diff
from CHECKINOUT a
join CHECKINOUT b
    on date(a.CHECKTIME) = date(b.CHECKTIME) and a.userid = b.userid
where
    a.CHECKTYPE = 'I'
    AND b.CHECKTYPE = 'O'
group by date(a.CHECKTIME), userid;
```

But as I wrote, there is a problem with the days where one of the I/O rows is missing and you need to either fix your data or specify what to do in such case.

Comment: with this script you get records for those non problematic logs which is very useful, then how can we get the names of those specific employee having problematic logs mean no check in but with checkout or vice versa, in short for those who have not computed by this script?

Comment: @Seryu I am planning to extend the answer with some possibilities of that when I have some time.